# How can I get my Flask app to automatically backup at a set time?

Tags: python, flask, shutil

I have a Flask app that already has the ability to be backed up locally to a .zip file using `shutil.make_archive()` which works when manually initiated via a menu from the front-end website. However, any attempt to have the method ran at, lets say, 1am every morning always returns an error, related to app context...

"RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information."

I've been doing a lot of research on app context with Flask and while the concept of it is making somewhat sense to me, I've failed in finding an actual implementation of this idea and thus a solution to my issue. Is this something that cannot be inherently fixed or is there a better solution to my problem? A snippet of my views.py file is below...

```
def backup_auto():
    # Declares paths for backup and source directory
    default_path = views.root_path.replace('\\program\\website','')
    default_backup = default_path + '\\backups'
    default_program = default_path + '\\program'

    # Gets current date and time for backup
    today = date.today()
    current_date = today.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
    str(current_date)

    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H.%M.%S")
    str(current_time)

    # Copies and zips the app into the backup folder
    shutil.make_archive(default_backup, 'zip', default_program) # Error occurs here

# Automatically performs backup at set rate
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=backup_auto, trigger="interval", seconds=43200)
scheduler.start()
# Shut down the scheduler when exiting the app
atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())
```

And here is my **init**.py file...

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'login1234'
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True

    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{USERS}'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
        'accounts' : f'sqlite:///{ACCOUNTS}',
        'expenses' : f'sqlite:///{EXPENSES}',
        'other_codes' : f'sqlite:///{OTHER_CODES}',
        'sheets' : f'sqlite:///{SHEETS}',
        'supervisors' : f'sqlite:///{SUPERVISORS}',
        'server' : f'sqlite:///{SERVER}',
        'changelog' : f'sqlite:///{CHANGELOG}'}

    db.init_app(app)

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth
    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

    from .models import User

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    # Initializes login manager and user loader
    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        return User.query.get(id)

    return app
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Is the snippet complete? It seems to be missing all flask-related parts

Comment: @AmmarAslam Sorry! I included my __init__.py code as well

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/appcontext/#manually-push-a-context…!?

Comment: When is create_app() called from the backup script? It seems to me that the backup script is calling some part of your code that uses a Flask related feature (possibly db tied to flask), but for that to work, flask needs to be initialised (the context of flask needs to be present)

Either untie your code from flask-related features (by creating a db engine yourself for jobs) or create a flask app before running the code.
You can create the app context and push it `app.app_context().push()` or use the with statement in the link